# How can I add multiple In-App purchases in iTunes Connect?

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, itunes

Usually i am going to
`iTunes connect -> my app -> Manage In-App Purchase` to add single item to the in app-purchase of my app.

I wanna to know if there is an API i can call it to add multiple files at once to the in-app purchase.

Help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such API. You should add all of them manually.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add them manually. And check them during request. Store the appId in array and send the appropriate id with request from array. This is the only way to handle Multiple inAppp

Answer (score 1):

No There is No Such API, You have to add them all for each tier you want to set.

for full app purchase setting and working check out [Reywenderlich Full In-App purchase implementation](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2797/introduction-to-in-app-purchases)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Application Loader from your Mac. There is a template there you can download and populate with your IAPs